# Create process remotely by Supervisord API

Tags: python, supervisord

I'm creating an application to manage my supervisord process. I want to create process remotely by this application using the API.

I've checked the [supervisord XML-RPC API](http://supervisord.org/api.html) but doesn't helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this interface to create process by API: https://github.com/mnaberez/supervisor_twiddler